# Error while testing Tensorflow Object Detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I've tried all steps of object_detection model installation mentioned @ 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

While testing the installation as mentioned in last step of article, I am getting below error.

```
ERROR: test_create_ssd_mobilenet_v1_model_from_config (__main__.ModelBuilderTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/RonakBhavsar/eDAM/ML/ObjectRecognition/models/object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 193, in test_create_ssd_mobilenet_v1_model_from_config
    model = self.create_model(model_proto)
  File "/Users/RonakBhavsar/eDAM/ML/ObjectRecognition/models/object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 53, in create_model
    return model_builder.build(model_config, is_training=False)
  File "/Users/RonakBhavsar/eDAM/ML/ObjectRecognition/models/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 73, in build
    return _build_ssd_model(model_config.ssd, is_training)
  File "/Users/RonakBhavsar/eDAM/ML/ObjectRecognition/models/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 126, in _build_ssd_model
    is_training)
  File "/Users/RonakBhavsar/eDAM/ML/ObjectRecognition/models/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 98, in _build_ssd_feature_extractor
    feature_extractor_config.conv_hyperparams, is_training)
  File "/Users/RonakBhavsar/eDAM/ML/ObjectRecognition/models/object_detection/builders/hyperparams_builder.py", line 70, in build
    hyperparams_config.regularizer),
  File "/Users/RonakBhavsar/eDAM/ML/ObjectRecognition/models/object_detection/builders/hyperparams_builder.py", line 119, in _build_regularizer
    return slim.l2_regularizer(scale=regularizer.l2_regularizer.weight)
  File "/Users/RonakBhavsar/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/regularizers.py", line 92, in l2_regularizer
    raise ValueError('scale cannot be an integer: %s' % (scale,))
ValueError: scale cannot be an integer: 1
```

I get this error for all the models mentioned in the test script. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We have a [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/1707) out that should fix this issue. Please give that a try.